# CKEditor remove all style and tags from combopanel (dropdown)

Tags: ckeditor

I use a custom CSS stylesheet for CKEditor and want to disable the preview of all styles and format tags on the dropdowns, and just display the name in a div for example. Right now CKEditor create the corresponding tag with the class to style a preview. (like on the screenshot) :
[image]

If in the dropdown there is a `h2` tag it will display it under `block elements` in a `h2` tag. It make the dropdown inherit the whole site style for `h2` tags.

I can do this by adding rules for the specific dropdown but was wondering is there is a built in configuration to stop that in a more generic way. Maybe to force it to always use simple span or div. To have just a classic dropdown, no groups, no style added.

Thanks for your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a brute force approach but you can override the list item style `.cke_panel_listItem` with some relevant children selectors in the `content.css` file.

In this example I'm controlling the display style of `h1`, `h2`, `h3` and `div` items in the list:

```
.cke_panel_listItem h1,
.cke_panel_listItem h2,
.cke_panel_listItem h3,
.cke_panel_listItem div {
    font-size: 12px !important;
    font-style: normal !important;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    color: #000000 !important;
    background-color: #ffffff !important;
    border: none !important;
 }
```

The original style definitions (such as those defined in ckeditor's `styles.js` file) will still be applied to the selected text, but the dropdown menu itself will display the labels using simple 12px text.

Comment: Yes that is what I already do, but I was wondering if the plugin itself had some parameter or something to force it to stop using the real tags and only plain `div` or anything but not `h2`, `h3` etc